# When are comments needed?

Tags: support, comments, flagging

Recently, I decided to clean up some old comments that should not be needed. I decided to go for low hanging fruits first, and went for [comments starting with "welcome"](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/1773787/find-comments-starting-with-text?CommentText=welcome) which either did not offer any more information other than the greeting, or they did ask for some information but the post was updated. I flagged a total of 32 over a couple of days.

To my surprise what I thought was a clear cut case, only 3 of the flags were marked helpful and 29 were declined.

These are comments from about the dawn of the site: 2014 and 2015. I sorted for oldest first before I went down the list to flag them.

I have included a full list of my recent comment flags at the end of the post.

As far as I was aware, at the time I was casting the "No longer needed" flags, I was doing it according to the guidance guidance that comments are not permanent, thus *can* and *should* be deleted when they do not offer any more use:

> ### When should comments be deleted?
>
> [Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). You should not expect them to be around forever. Once a clarification has been made, an edit added to the post to include new information, or the issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it can be deleted. Additionally, any comment that violates the comment guidelines listed above or the [Code of Conduct](/conduct) is subject to deletion.
>
> In reality, on most sites, many since-obsolete or guideline-violating comments don't end up being deleted due to the high volume of comments posted, but this does not mean that they can't or shouldn't be deleted in the future.
>
> If you encounter a comment that has since become obsolete or that violates the commenting guidelines above or the Code of Conduct, you can [flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/) it for deletion.

[From Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757)

> Comments are second-class citizens, so they may be deleted without any explanation and any reason and no-one will care.

[From Worldbuilding Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6277)

> Comments are second-class (or even third-class) citizens on Stack Exchange, and can be deleted at almost any time for almost any reason, with or without diamond moderator involvement.

[From Worldbuilding Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6683)

If my flags were indeed wrong, then there should be a written guidance for what can and cannot be flagged. This should be added up as part of the [FAQ](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).

---

### Declined

> Welcome to Worldbuilding and StackExchange in general :-) We look forward to seeing you around the site

Comment from: 2014-10-02 15:09:36Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/824/is-there-an-effective-way-to-design-a-realistic-religion-for-a-world/826#comment1595_826)

> Welcome to worldbuilding, good answer :)

Comment from: 2014-10-03 13:16:45Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/882/tactical-influences-of-an-entirely-electricity-based-arsenal-on-starships/956#comment1800_956)

> Welcome to Worldbuilding! This is a good overview of how life forms, but I don't think it properly addresses the question. Can you expand it to better cover the criteria?

Comment from: 2014-10-20 23:44:17Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2711/can-two-civilizations-on-nearby-stars-develop-independently-but-be-at-a-similar/2915#comment5500_2915)

Additional information: [the last edit to the post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/2915/revisions#rev-body-6e557eee-9a7d-4258-8015-09092d0970db) is from 2014-10-21 10:24:31Z. I felt the edit expanded the answer in satisfactory manner.

> Welcome to Worldbuilding! This is a good, commonsense post; I like it.

Comment from: 2014-10-22 01:36:19Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/425/assuming-magic-is-a-source-of-energy-that-wizards-have-access-to-how-would-they/2962#comment5605_2962)

> Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment from: 2014-12-13 03:17:11Z

> I'm hardly new to stack exchange. I've been frustrated by the low-reputation trap on several different stack exchange sites for a few years. Apparently I have a much easier time thinking of small improvements to existing answers than of whole new answers (or questions).

Comment from: 2014-12-13 03:32:02Z

> Eventually you get enough rep that they give you a +100 boost when you join a new SE site. Not that that helps you right now :(

Comment from: 2014-12-13 03:43:30Z

> .. and by coincidence I hit that threshold today, thanks to some upvotes to an answer on SuperUser. About a year after I started trying.

Comment from: 2014-12-13 07:11:32Z 
[Link to post with this comment chain](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/6445)

Additional information: conversation between two people. Seems entirely useless mere hours after it ended. The second comment mentions [the association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work) and the last comment is from about four hours later, and indicates the post author received the association bonus. That all happened 8.5 years ago.

> Welcome to the site. Excellent first post.

Comment from: 2015-01-07 18:40:41Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/7301/how-to-explain-the-co-existence-of-peace-and-violence-in-religion/8400#comment17466_8400)

> Welcome to Worldbuilding :-)

Comment from: 2015-01-23 08:58:25Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9128/a-continent-lost-underwater/9132#comment20043_9132)

> Welcome to the site orkoden

Comment from: 2015-02-16 19:25:31Z  
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9947/could-a-dwarven-civilization-exist/10375#comment23601_10375)

> Welcome to the site WeRelic

Comment from: 2015-02-16 19:53:28Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10377/expanding-your-empires-space-from-the-inside-can-it-be-useful/10381#comment23604_10381)

> Welcome to the site Inquisitive

Comment from: 2015-02-16 19:54:07Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10340/how-do-i-encourage-fully-armored-knights-to-carry-a-shield/10380#comment23605_10380)

> Welcome to the site! For future reference, you should include the "why" and the "how" in your answers. Your answer might be correct, but it is very rarely constructive without further description.

Comment from: 2015-02-23 17:06:40Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10717/time-required-for-isolated-colonists-to-forget-about-their-origin/10722#comment24553_10722)

Additional information: [the last edit to the post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/10722/revisions#rev-body-5a332b41-60c9-4c5d-93a2-d8b221222ea2) is from 2015-02-23 18:30:19Z. I felt the edit added the "why" and "how" in a satisfactory manner.

> Welcome to the site Shion. This is an excellently detailed question. I look forward to seeing what kind of answers you get.

Comment from: 2015-03-05 18:52:37Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11412/help-with-designing-currency#comment26409_11412)

> Welcome to worldbuilding, nice answer. :)

Comment from: 2015-03-05 21:55:17Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11408/technology-without-heavier-elements/11434#comment26439_11434)

> Welcome to the site. You may want to take that last question out and go ask it over on the Earth Sciences SE.

Comment from: 2015-03-06 03:29:29Z

> @James I will, filler

Comment from: 2015-03-06 03:29:57Z 
[Link to post with this comment chain](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/11448)

> Welcome to Worldbuilding.se! Can you add a link which points to a source for Steven Pinker's and Michael Shermer's opinions? Also, as many individuals in this site may not know who these people are, can you say why their opinions are important?

Comment from: 2015-02-22 04:41:32Z

> Answer edited pursuant to request.

Comment from: 2015-02-22 04:53:11Z 
[Link to post with this comment chain](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/10649)

Additional information: [the last edit to the post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/10649/revisions#rev-body-28312ed7-6efd-4f70-8cb2-adb7adc3cb1f) is from 2015-02-22 04:52:47Z. I felt the edit added the required information to a satisfactory manner.

> Welcome to the site! Please check the [tour](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to get a better idea about what this specific SE site is about.

Comment from 2015-03-17 18:29:13Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12137/organisations-that-inlcude-industries-in-their-name#comment28314_12137)

> Welcome to the site Paolo.

Comment from: 2015-03-18 16:06:07Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/keeping-secrets-in-a-thought-reverberating-hall/12207#comment28509_12207)

> Welcome to the worldbuilding stack exchange! To improve this answer (and get more rep!), I suggest going into specific building materials and how Forevertown will replicate its buildings and infrastructure. We do like specifics here. :)

Comment from: 2015-03-20 22:44:45Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12266/a-city-to-last-ten-million-years-construction/12436#comment29270_12436)

Additional information: [the last edit to the post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/12436/revisions#rev-body-129bc0d9-8f2b-473e-b2f6-ff8481b0e01e) is from 2015-03-20 23:05:05Z. I felt the edit expanded the answer in satisfactory manner.

> Welcome to the worldbuilding stack exchange!

Comment from: 2015-03-20 22:39:25Z

> @PipperChip Thank you for using the short version and not the usual 'this is how you should be doing things' greeting that most people do.

Comment from: 2015-08-07 02:19:42Z  
[Link to post with this comment chain](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/12434)

> Welcome to Worldbuilding!

Comment from: 2015-03-31 12:25:43Z  
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13409/can-the-present-human-understand-people-in-the-past-verbally/13420#comment32057_13420)

> Welcome to the site Malandy.

Comment from: 2015-04-13 15:31:25Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14153/how-long-would-it-take-to-train-a-medieval-village-girl-to-be-a-swordsgirl#comment34395_14153)

> Welcome to the site kuhl. Interesting answer.

Comment from: 2015-04-14 16:22:46Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14300/how-can-i-explain-a-planet-with-perpetual-rain/14305#comment34613_14305)

> Welcome to the site! Please consider expanding on your answer. As it currently stands it is a link-only answer and as such is not a good fit for this site.

Comment from: 2015-04-15 17:07:58Z 
[Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14363/do-xenobiologists-exist/14412#comment34922_14412)

Additional information: [the last edit to the post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/14412/revisions#rev-body-00f01807-c2e9-4ca5-ab32-e7f16e5150f9) is from 2015-04-16 06:51:37Z. I felt the edit successfully the answer not link-only.

### Helpful

- 2 on [this post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2915)

  - Of these, [1 still remains](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2711/can-two-civilizations-on-nearby-stars-develop-independently-but-be-at-a-similar/2915#comment5500_2915):

    > Welcome to Worldbuilding! This is a good overview of how life forms, but I don't think it properly addresses the question. Can you expand it to better cover the criteria?
- 1 on [this post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/14189)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was under the wrong idea that also deleted comments would have counted as edits and as a consequence bumped the related posts up.

Since I saw no reason for bumping so many posts up, I opted for declining the flags.

But a quick experiment proved that my idea was wrong, and therefore I could have accepted those flags.

My apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: I'll add that we've gone through the flags again and have deleted comments as needed.